# ¿Como crear imagenes teniendo el body vacío en javascript y capturar los eventos?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, img

Hola estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio, pero al darle clic me da error, al crear dicho elemento, aunque me parece que estoy poniendo mal la lógica del código, la idea es crear un elemento con la primer a imagen y que luego con el teclado vaya mostrando cada una de ellas, desplazándose con las flechas del teclado.

Esto es lo que tendría que hacer el código :

- Partiendo de un documento html con el body vacío, añade el código
  javascript necesario para crear un un botón que al pulsarlo cree un
  elemento con la primera imagen, captura los eventos de teclado de
  forma que podamos mostrar cada una de las imágenes desplazándonos con
  las flechas del teclado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var boton = document.createElement("button");
        boton.innerHTML = "Crear Imagen";
        document.body.appendChild(boton);

        boton.onclick = function() {
            //alert("Has hecho click");
            var myImage = new Image(100,200);
            var imagen = document.createElement(myImage.src = 'img/1.png');
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            br.innerHTML = "<br>";
            document.body.appendChild(br);
            document.body.appendChild(imagen);
            
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el error que me da al crear el primer elemento, no se como hacer los eventos del teclado.

```
Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('img/1.png') is not a valid name.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 26,
  "colno": 35
}
```

Comment: Deberías subir también el tipo de error que recibes. No veo en tu código ningún evento para capturar las flechas del teclado, el que tienes es para eventos de tipo click.

Comment: Tu error se debe a que `createElement` espera recibir el nombre de una etiqueta html y tu le diste esto `myImage.src = 'img/1.png'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas que faltan. Te dejo un código donde se puede cambiar imágenes con las flechas del teclado o clicando en los botones. Las imágenes deben encontrarse al interno de una carpeta llamada `img` y deben llamarse `img1.png`, `img2.png`, etc.

> Consejo: Te lo dejo como ejemplo, pero aunque tu profesor te dé 10 puntos, tener estos conocimientos vale más que una nota. El ejercicio es muy fácil de hacer y debes tomar mi ayuda como una guía para seguir mejorando no para hacer tu vida escolar más fácil para que la laboral luego te sea imposible. Todos hemos estado ahí, así que ¡animo! y a seguir estudiando.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Creación de los elementos html
        var boton1 = document.createElement("button");
            boton1.innerHTML = "<";
            boton1.style.width = "100px";
        var boton2 = document.createElement("button");
            boton2.innerHTML = ">";
            boton2.style.width = "100px";
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.height = 100;
            img.width = 200;
        var Inum = 1;

        // Inserción de los elementos html
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(boton1);
        document.body.appendChild(boton2);

        // Cambiar imagen con las flechas del teclado
        document.onkeydown = checkKey;                
        function checkKey(e) {

            // Compatibilidad con navegadores
            e = e || window.event;

            if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                // flecha izquierda
                if (Inum >= 2){Inum--} // controla que Inum sea superior a 1 (img0 no existe)
                img.src = 'img/img'+Inum+'.png';
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                // flecha derecha
                if (Inum <=2){Inum++} // controla que Inum no sea superior al número de imagenes (uso: si hay 10 img usar el número 9)
                img.src = 'img/img'+Inum+'.png';
            }
        }

        // Cambiar imagen con los botones
        boton1.onclick = function() {
            // imagen anterior
            if (Inum >= 2){Inum--} // controla que Inum sea superior a 1
            img.src = 'img/img'+Inum+'.png';
        };
        boton2.onclick = function() {
            // imagen siguiente
            if (Inum <=2){Inum++} // controla que Inum no sea superior al número de imagenes
            img.src = 'img/img'+Inum+'.png';
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias @Ariel Montes, tienes razón, seguiré esforzándome, e intentaré desarrollar la lógica del ejercicio con el ejemplo, aunque el material que nos da es poca cosa para aprender a programar en condiciones, un saludo !

Comment: Comentaré más el código para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: gracias ! la verdad es que la lógica es bastante sencilla y la he entendido, ojala hubieran profesores así ! jeje un saludo !

Comment: Muchas gracias David. He corregido un error en la lógica de los botones y comentado el código, he añadido también un control para que no se intente cargar imágenes que no existen.

Comment: Gracias @Ariel Montes por la ayuda, la verdad es que así se agradece aprender programación, al ser a distancia y no tener nada mas que apuntes de internet, y temario mas o menos actualizado, para aprender es una locura, aunque imagino que en el mundo laboral será más o menos igual, un saludo.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta y mucho mejor consejo!

Answer (score 2):

El problema que hay a la hora de crear las imágenes es que la estas creando con dos variables diferentes. Una el objeto y otra la ruta. Te vale únicamente con la variable `myImage`, asignándole la ruta de la imagen y luego añadiendo ese elemento al DOM en vez de la variable `imagen`.

Para poder desplazarse por las imágenes hace falta capturar el evento de teclado. Te pongo la solución a la parte correspondiente de código que tienes para mostrar imágenes.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    var boton = document.createElement("button");
    boton.innerHTML = "Crear Imagen";
    document.body.appendChild(boton);

    boton.onclick = function() {
        //alert("Has hecho click");
        var myImage = new Image(100,200);
        myImage.src = 'img/1.png';
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        br.innerHTML = "<br>";
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(myImage);
        
    };
</script>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @Miguel27, es lo que estaba buscando, ahora intentaré capturar los eventos en dichas imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas la variable **myImage** ya estás creando el elemento "img" y tu lo que haces es crear el elemento "img" con el New Image(100,200) y luego intentar generar otro elemento "img" con el elemento ya creado **myImage** y no hace falta.

Te adjunto un link: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var boton = document.createElement("button");
        boton.innerHTML = "Crear Imagen";
        document.body.appendChild(boton);

        boton.onclick = function() {
            //alert("Has hecho click");
            var myImage = new Image(100,200);
            myImage.src = 'img/1.png';
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            br.innerHTML = "<br>";
            document.body.appendChild(br);
            document.body.appendChild(myImage);
            
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```